# How to change already shown tooltip?

Tags: javascript, css

The tooltip is normally shown onmouseover event.
So when tooltip comes up - I want to change it to new one after e.g. 10 sec.
So everytime you hover a mouse cursor it bring up tooltip1 then in 10 sec. it's changed to tooltip2. Then when you hover a mouse cursor again it starts with tooltip1 again.

Or as an option - just show one tooltip but after 10 seconds...

Thanks

Comment: What tooltip are you referring to? An element's title attribute?

Comment: sorry for confusion.. Yes, it's element title attribute...

Comment: Are you trying to change it while you are still hovering or just the next time you hover?  I don't know that you can force the title text that shows up whenever you hover your cursor to change without causing that bubble to disappear first (at least in Firefox).

Comment: I suggest reworking the concept as a whole. Consider using JQuery to show a custom tooltip using a <div>

Comment: I would also claim that it's not possible with the browser default tooltips. Try using a jquery tooltip instead. This is one of many: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/simple-tooltip-with-jquery-only-text/

Comment: OK.. let's not replace but just delay it for 10 seconds to appear.. Any thoughts . ?

Comment: Depending of your needs, you may be better off having your own tooltip instead of hacking your way through the builtin tooltip and the title attribute.

Comment: Hacks here are especially a bad idea given that this is a very simple feature to implement and customize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using a jquery plugin such as [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) or [jquery tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). But this kind of does what you are looking for: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wenkqLde/)

html:

```
<div class="tooltip-change" title="title 1">Hover over me</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip-change').on('mouseover', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.tooltip-change').attr('title', 'title 2');
        }, 5000);
    });

    $('.tooltip-change').on('mouseout', function () {
        $('.tooltip-change').attr('title', 'title 1');
    });
});
```

Only problem with that is that the native title tooltip does not update its display unless the cursor is moved over the html element. Title changes in that after 5 seconds instead of 10 to make the effect quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with timer which changes title of your element as below

```
function changeToolTip(){

    //do ajax or something to bring your new tool tip here
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').title = 'your new title';

    setTimeout(changeToolTip, 10000);
}
```

Now call this code once in your script and it will get called to change title every 10 seconds.